# How to auto zoom in when using webview to open a website?

Tags: android, webview

```
s.setDefaultZoom(ZoomDensity.CLOSE);
```

I tried to use this but it does not work.

```
        // Configure the webview
       WebSettings s = getSettings();
       s.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
       s.setDefaultZoom(ZoomDensity.CLOSE);
   s.setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.NARROW_COLUMNS);
   s.setUseWideViewPort(false);
   s.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
   s.setSavePassword(true);
   s.setSaveFormData(true);
   s.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Any help will be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
    webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webview.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);     
    webview.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
```